# strcpy throws memory exception

Tags: c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char *a="hello";
    char *b;
    strcpy(b,a);
     cout<<b;


    return 0;
}
```

This code theows memory exception . why ?

Comment: i am a bit rusty in C++, how does it work if you add the \0 at the end of a ? if you import string.h why don't you use strings instead of char* ?

Comment: @Davide: a string literal already has a \0 implicitly.  `string.h` is the C string header, with support for ASCIIZ strings, and operating on them tends to involve `char*`s or arrays.  `std::string` is in `<string>` (i.e. without the `.h`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`char* b` is a pointer that is yet to be pointed at any memory... it simply holds a random address.  You attempt to copy the content of `a` over the memory at that address.  Instead, first point `b` at some memory - either a local array or from `new char[]`.

```
char buffer[128];
char* b = buffer;

char* b = new char[128];
// use b for a while...
delete[] b; // release memory when you've finished with it...
          // don't read/write data through b afterwards!
```

( or simply copy it directly into `buffer` :-) )

BTW, C++ has a `<string>` header that's much, much easier to use:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "hello";
    std::string t = s;
    std::cout << t << '\n';   // '\n' is a "newline"
}
```

If you're writing new code, prefer std::string, but sooner or later you'll need to know about all that `char*` stuff too, especially when C++ code needs to interact with C libraries.

Comment: +1 for mentioning both solutions and not telling OP to use `malloc` :).

Comment: You should also mention correct usage of `delete` for the array :) or OP is going to be having dragons flying off his nose ;)

Answer (score 2):

Exception is due to uninitialized,

```
char *b;
```

Either allocate `b` on stack as an array,

```
char b[SIZE];
```

Or allocate using `new` and later `delete` it. But the best way is,

```
std::string b;
b = a;
```

Comment: Not really, it is actually because there is no memory allocation.

Comment: I posted the comment while i saw the answer only as `Exception is due to uninitialized,` it's all good now. You should also probably add new and delete based examle.

Answer (score 1):

`b` is uninitialised. It is a pointer, but it doesn't point anywhere (it holds `NULL` or a garbage value). `strcpy` tries to write to it, but it must have a pointer to write to. You must assign some chunk of memory to `b` before you can use it. Eg:

```
char *b = new char[20];  //dynamically allocate some memory
```

or

```
char b[20];  //allocate some memory on the stack
```

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
char *b;
strcpy(b,a);
```

`b` is not initialized - using its value is undefined behavior. Even if using its value is okay on your platform it holds "whatever" address - copying a string onto "whatever address" is undefined behavior.

You have to allocate a memory block by any legal means and set `b` to start of that block. The block must be large enough to hold the string together with terminating null character.

Answer (score 1):

A few things are "wrong" with your code.

1. Use:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   ```
2. You're not using C++ strings.

   ```
   std::string a = "hello";
   std::string b = a;
   ```

---

If you insist on using `strcpy()`, please allocate some memory for `b`:

```
b = new char[strlen(a)];

// Your code here

delete[] b;
```

There's lots of memory to go around. No need to go about corrupting stuff.

Comment: You allocated memory with `new []` you should deallocate with `delete []`

Answer (score 0):

```
strcpy(dest, source)
```

In your code b is your dest and it is not initialized. Even if you switch them around it will still crash because you have not allocated memory for b. The destination memory has to be pre-allocated.

Comment: `b` is not empty - it is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory (e.g. using `malloc`) for the destination before you can copy something there.

Comment: Yes. Use `malloc()` and `strcpy()` in **C++**. Very nice.

Comment: @muntoo And don't forget the `.h` after include files.

Answer (score 0):

The char pointer b is initiaized to 0 when the program runs.  So you can't copy anything to it.

If you want to copy a string, in C++ style, do this instead:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a = "hello";
    string b = a;
    cout << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```